# bundle exit status: 20 "You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm from Russia. Recently I started to get interested in programming. I got an application for maintenance. I'm having difficulties that I can't solve. Tell me please.

```
 01 Warning, new version of rvm available '1.29.12', you are using older version '1.29.7'.
      01 You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
      01 You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
      01 You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
#<Thread:0x00007f7f9804f7f8@/home/strongest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@runall/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /home/strongest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@runall/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/strongest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@runall/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deployer@88.212.253.144: bundle exit status: 20 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
bundle stdout: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
bundle stderr: Warning, new version of rvm available '1.29.12', you are using older version '1.29.7'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployer@88.212.253.144: bundle exit status: 20
bundle stdout: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
bundle stderr: Warning, new version of rvm available '1.29.12', you are using older version '1.29.7'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 20
bundle stdout: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
bundle stderr: Warning, new version of rvm available '1.29.12', you are using older version '1.29.7'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deployer@88.212.253.144: bundle exit status: 20
bundle stdout: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
bundle stderr: Warning, new version of rvm available '1.29.12', you are using older version '1.29.7'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


 DEBUG [ebd1fa0b] Command: cd /home/deployer/runall/releases/20210727112514 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.5.1@runall do bundle config --local path /home/deployer/runall/shared/bundle

 DEBUG [ebd1fa0b]   You are replacing the current local value of path, which is currently nil

  INFO [ebd1fa0b] Finished in 1.006 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

  INFO [3674b7d0] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.5.1@runall do bundle config --local without development:test as deployer@88.212.253.144

 DEBUG [3674b7d0] Command: cd /home/deployer/runall/releases/20210727112514 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.5.1@runall do bundle config --local without development:test

 DEBUG [3674b7d0]   You are replacing the current local value of without, which is currently nil

  INFO [3674b7d0] Finished in 1.028 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [8a8d36f0] Running if test ! -d /home/deployer/runall/releases/20210727112514; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/runall/releases/20210727112514'" 1>&2; false; fi as deployer@88.212.253.144

 DEBUG [8a8d36f0] Command: if test ! -d /home/deployer/runall/releases/20210727112514; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/runall/releases/20210727112514'" 1>&2; false; fi

 DEBUG [8a8d36f0] Finished in 0.166 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [fbbcc8d9] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.5.1@runall do bundle check as deployer@88.212.253.144

 DEBUG [fbbcc8d9] Command: cd /home/deployer/runall/releases/20210727112514 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.5.1@runall do bundle check

 DEBUG [fbbcc8d9]   You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.

 DEBUG [fbbcc8d9] Finished in 1.255 seconds with exit status 20 (failed).

  INFO [ed3ab2bb] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.5.1@runall do bundle install --jobs 4 --quiet as deployer@88.212.253.144

 DEBUG [ed3ab2bb] Command: cd /home/deployer/runall/releases/20210727112514 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.5.1@runall do bundle install --jobs 4 --quiet

 DEBUG [ed3ab2bb]   Warning, new version of rvm available '1.29.12', you are using older version '1.29.7'.

You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc

You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc

 DEBUG [ed3ab2bb]   You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.

00:23 sidekiq:start
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.5.1@runall do bundle exec sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile /home/deployer/runall/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.pid --environment production --logfile /home/deployer/runall/shared/log/si…
      01 bundler: failed to load command: sidekiq (/home/deployer/runall/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/sidekiq)
      01 Bundler::LockfileError: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
      01   /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version'
      01   /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:95:in `initialize'
      01   /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:84:in `new'
      01   /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:84:in `initialize'
      01   /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/dsl.rb:218:in `new'
      01   /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/dsl.rb:218:in `to_definition'
      01   /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/dsl.rb:13:in `evaluate'
      01   /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:35:in `build'
      01   /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:135:in `definition'
      01   /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
      01   /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
      01   /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
      01   /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
#<Thread:0x000055662e3daa88@/home/strongest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@runall/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /home/strongest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@runall/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/strongest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@runall/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deployer@88.212.253.144: sidekiq exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
sidekiq stdout: bundler: failed to load command: sidekiq (/home/deployer/runall/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/sidekiq)
sidekiq stderr: Bundler::LockfileError: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:95:in `initialize'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:84:in `new'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:84:in `initialize'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/dsl.rb:218:in `new'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/dsl.rb:218:in `to_definition'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/dsl.rb:13:in `evaluate'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:35:in `build'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:135:in `definition'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /home/strongest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@runall/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/strongest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@runall/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deployer@88.212.253.144: sidekiq exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
sidekiq stdout: bundler: failed to load command: sidekiq (/home/deployer/runall/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/sidekiq)
sidekiq stderr: Bundler::LockfileError: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:95:in `initialize'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:84:in `new'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:84:in `initialize'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/dsl.rb:218:in `new'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/dsl.rb:218:in `to_definition'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/dsl.rb:13:in `evaluate'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:35:in `build'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:135:in `definition'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
  /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Gemfile.lock` in structured for Bundler 2.
The Error cause in that stack trace is:

```
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
```

You should either get Bundler 2 on the remote server, or downgrade locally, and downgrade the `Gemfile.lock` file to `< 2`.

**See also:**

- https://bundler.io/guides/bundler_2_upgrade.html